# Non deprecated method in Joomla! 4 to load user by userid

Tags: extensions, user, joomla-4, jfactory, deprecated

I'm looking for an extension for Joomla! 4.0 to replace a deprecated method which was used to load an user by userid. The method used actually is:

```
$user = Factory::getUser($userid);
```

The issue is that in the error log it is recommended to use `Factory::getApplication()->getIdentity()` instead, but this method doesn't accept params! The other method that I found is `Factory::getApplication()->loadIdentity()`, but this one accepts User object as its parameter.

So which is the non-deprecated method to load a user object by passing userid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Joomla\CMS\User\UserFactory`. You can get it from the service container:

```
use Joomla\CMS\User\UserFactoryInterface;

$userFactory = $container->get(UserFactoryInterface::class);
```

Or using alias:

```
$userFactory = $container->get('user.factory');
```

Where `$container` is the container. If you're doing this inside service provider file (`services/provider.php`), it's already defined. Otherwise, if using container as service locator inside your classes, get it from main factory:

```
$container = \Joomla\CMS\Factory::getContainer();
```

To create a user instance:

```
$user = $userFactory->loadUserById($id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used @Sharky's (thanks!) solution like:

```
use Joomla\CMS\User\UserFactoryInterface;

$user = Factory::getContainer()->get(UserFactoryInterface::class)->loadUserById($userid);
```